# Execute a SQL statement prepared by another SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Is it possible to execute a ALTER INDEX prepared by doing a SELECT on sys tables in Oracle 12c. Please see below

I am trying to find the unused indexes for which I have prepared the alter statements by select clause below -

```
SELECT 'alter index ' || owner || '.' || index_name || ' monitoring usage;'
FROM dba_indexes
WHERE owner NOT in (
        'SYSTEM',
        'SYS');
```

Next, I will have to manually copy the output of this SQL to a new SQL commander tab and execute them. Rather is it possible to execute these statements directly instead of showing them?

I am trying to achieve this in SQL only, as a single statement executable from any SQL utility like DBViz or SQL+, and NOT IN PL/SQL or Unix.

Comment: what's wrong with plsql? anon block, select into a varchar and then use execute immediate https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130

Comment: The short answer is "no". If you are familiar with Unix tools, you may be thinking "command expansion" or similar. There are no such facilities in SQL. Situations like this are among the main reasons PL/SQL was invented.

Comment: Already discussed that route. Hard to convince a multi tier company/project to introduce a new tech which most of their people don't know about. If it is a single statement and a F5 it is easier to get approvals and easier to implement. If it is not possible then conventional method is just fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is it not possible only in Oracle. Do others like PostgreSql or newer DBs like Teradata or Redshift have new functions to support this

Answer (score 7):

You can do this two ways:

1- Spoofing the result to a file and running the file.

```
set pages 0 lines 200 feed off term off
spool _file
SELECT 'alter index ' || owner || '.' || index_name || ' monitoring usage;'
FROM dba_indexes
WHERE owner NOT in ('SYSTEM','SYS');
spool off
@_file
```

1- Or via PL/SQL

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec in (select owner, index_name FROM dba_indexes WHERE owner NOT in ('SYSTEM','SYS'))
   LOOP
      query := 'alter index ' || rec.owner || '.' || rec.index_name || ' monitoring usage'
      execute immediate query;
   END LOOP;
end;
/
```

Comment: When using execute immediate you musn't use a semicolon at the end. This leads to errors. Id correct it myself but i dont know what else to change as your anwser fits in all other points and you need to edit at least 7 characters.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test my script. I changed now. THanks

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on solution 1. Where can I execute this block? As I mentioned in my question, I am not looking for a PL/SQL solution

Comment: @Neena Solution 1 is run from SQL Plus.

Comment: @Neena, it's sqlplus. The only issue that could happen is @_file instruction ask for an extension ".sql" ... I didn't test this script, but that's the idea of running scripts in sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT 'alter index ' || owner || '.' || index_name || ' monitoring usage;'
FROM dba_indexes
WHERE owner NOT in (
        'SYSTEM',
        'SYS');)
```

Comment: Please add some explain to your solution